# smooth scrolling recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

```
  public class Maindashboard extends AppCompatActivity {

            ArrayList<SectionDataModel> allSampleData;
            private Toolbar toolbar;
            public static TextView title;

            public static RecyclerView my_recycler_view;

            @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                getSupportActionBar().hide();
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
                allSampleData = new ArrayList<SectionDataModel>();              
                title = findViewById(R.id.title);       
                ArrayList<String> years = new ArrayList<String>();
                int thisYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) + 10;
                for (int ik = 2019; ik <= thisYear; ik++) {
                    years.add(Integer.toString(ik));
                    int year = ik;    
                }                  
                my_recycler_view = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_item);        
                my_recycler_view.setHasFixedSize(true);        
        RecyclerViewDataAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewDataAdapter(Maindashboard.this, allSampleData);        
   my_recycler_view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
                my_recycler_view.setItemViewCacheSize(20);
                my_recycler_view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                my_recycler_view.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
                my_recycler_view.setRecycledViewPool(new RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool());   
                my_recycler_view.setAdapter(adapter);        
                createDummyData();
            }    
            public void createDummyData() {    
                for (int j = 0; j < 132; j++) {    
                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                    SectionDataModel dm = new SectionDataModel();
                    ArrayList<SingleItemModel> singleItem = new ArrayList<SingleItemModel>();
                    // cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 2019);    
                    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month + j);
                    SimpleDateFormat dfs = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM-yyyy");
                    String months = dfs.format(cal.getTime());    
                    dm.setHeaderTitle(months);
                    int maxDay = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);       
                    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yyyy");
                    //System.out.print(df.format(cal.getTime()));
                    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
                    int dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
                    for (int i = 1; i < maxDay + dayOfWeek; i++) {        
                        SingleItemModel imageModel = new SingleItemModel();
                            if (i < dayOfWeek) {
                            imageModel.setName(" - - ");
                        } else {       
                            int index = i - dayOfWeek + 1;
                            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, index);
                            imageModel.setName(df.format(cal.getTime()));    
                        }
                        singleItem.add(imageModel);        
                    }
                    dm.setAllItemsInSection(singleItem);        
                    allSampleData.add(dm);
                }                 
            }        
            public int getWeekdayOfMonth(int year, int month) {
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.set(year, month - 1, 1);
                int dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1;
                return dayOfWeek;
            }
        }
```

i created custom vertical scrolling 10 years  calendar view  its working fine but not scrolling smoothly and when open calendar screen it taking to 5 seconds to open activity  i used below code  in that code executing perfectly but not scrolling smoothly and taking to much time top open activity

Answer (score 1):

> Try this,this might help

```
 recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false); already used no changes in scrolling